# Can i see from which branch was last deployed in capistrano

Tags: git, symfony, capistrano, bitbucket

So I have a DEV server, from which all deploys happen.
We develop on different branches, and deploy them randomly for testing.

Is there a way to check the branch that was checked out during the last deploy? Or do i have to keep track manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using `capistrano 3.11`. Whenever I successfully deploy, capistrano creates a `revisions.log` file inside your deployed app folder. Which will have something like bellow

```
Branch feature_branch (at ab2d06d889894c1a21101dd50) deployed as release 20190108100932 by deployer
```

Answer (score 10):

There is a file `current/REVISION` which contains the hash of the deployed commit. And you can run `git branch -a --contains <commit>` to get the branches which contains this commit.